# JUnit: Test exception doesn't work (AssertionError: Expected exception even if exception thrown)

Tags: java, exception, testing, junit, assert

I'm trying to test my class for a Exception. I've been trying a couple different methods, nothing works. What am I doing wrong here?

The class I'm trying to test, PrimeNumber.java:

```
public class PrimeNumber {

    static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger("Log");

    private String primeNumberStr;

    public PrimeNumber(String primeNumberStr) {
        this.primeNumberStr = primeNumberStr;
    }

    public String getPrimeResult() {
        String resultStr = "";
        try {
            // Convert user input to int
            int primeNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(primeNumberStr);
            // Beginning of return message
            resultStr += primeNumberInt + " is ";
            // Add "not" if it's not a prime
            if (!Primes.isPrime(primeNumberInt))
                resultStr += "NOT ";
            // End return message
            resultStr += "a prime";
            // If not a valid number, catch
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Log exception
            LOG.warn("NumberFormatException" + e.getMessage());
            // If empty user input
            if (primeNumberStr.length() == 0)
                resultStr += "No number inserted";
            // Else not empty but not valid
            else
                resultStr += primeNumberStr + " is not a valid number";
            resultStr += ". Only numbers without decimals are accepted.";
        }

        return resultStr;
    }

}
```

And now things I've tried to test:

With annotation

```
@Test(expected = NumberFormatException.class)
public void testNumberFormatExceptionBeingThrown() {
    PrimeNumber primeNumber = new PrimeNumber("6dg");
    primeNumber.getPrimeResult();
}
```

Results in failed test and:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.Exception
```

---

With a JUnit rule:

```
@Rule public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test(expected = NumberFormatException.class)
public void testNumberFormatExceptionBeingThrown() {
    thrown.expect(NumberFormatException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("For input string: \"a21\"");
    PrimeNumber primeNumber = new PrimeNumber("a21");
    primeNumber.getPrimeResult();
}
```

Results in:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw (an instance of java.lang.NumberFormatException and exception with message a string containing "For input string: \"a21\"")
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.failDueToMissingException(ExpectedException.java:263)
at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$200(ExpectedException.java:106)
at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:245)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

---

Comment: Well, none of your methods you posted throw a `NumberFormatException`. Certainly the constructor doesn't. Why would you think it would? All you do in the constructor is assign a `String` to a `String` field. I'm confused as to why you wrote code that does everything possible to avoid exceptions from being thrown, and then expect it to throw exceptions.

Comment: Forgot one line of code (calling the getPrimeResult() method). But I guess I've misunderstood something about testing exceptions. So it's not possible to test an exception that has been catched? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @asmb You test a method with `expected = ` if that method propagates that exception to the calling method. So the test method (or the test runner) can catch it and check if the catched exception matches expected one. If you catch the exception yourself, then you can't test it like this.

Comment: Why test something that was caught? It usually makes more sense to test the outputs of your functions. An exception is an output only if it gets out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything's working as it should. You've successfully been able to **prevent** your methods from throwing exceptions. You've successfully been able to test that they **do** throw exceptions.

It's just, it doesn't make sense to do both at the same time. **You need to decide** if you want each method to throw an exception or not when given wrong arguments.

**If you do** want a method to throw an exception when given a wrong argument, then don't catch and handle the exception, just let it be thrown. Then, test that your method throws that exception, like you did above.

**If you don't** want the method to throw an exception when given a wrong argument, then decide what you want it to do instead. Then, test that your method does what you want it to. If it throws an exception, the test will fail.

---

That said, the way you handle numbers in your class doesn't make much sense. You're getting them as `String`s, storing them as `String`s, and returning them as `String`s, but whenever you work with them, you convert them back and forth to `int`s. Why not just use `int` everywhere in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Your `getPrimeResult` is actually dealing with the exception as opposed to allowing it to propagate any further in the call stack.  Hence, it's not being thrown, and the test will never be able to intercept it and assert against it (in that state).

While I think that this is a better approach, if you want to propagate it through the call stack, you would need to `throw` it after you've caught it.

```
// after the assignment to resultStr
throw e;
```